# What is the right place for javax.validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, dependencies

I am working on a simple project as a point of reference for new projects or to try new technologies. The project has Hibernate & Spring capabilities.

I tried to add some anotations for validate fields. Those are the validation which I am using

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

The problem is that I need **javax.validation** dependecy and There are **[a lot of jars](http://www.findmaven.net/find/class/javax.validation.constraints.NotNull)** which includes those clases but none of Spring or Hibernate.

Which one is the standard?

Note: I check the dependency in the big project and I am using the [validation-api](http://www.findmaven.net/detail/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the library  "Apache Geronimo JSR-303 Bean Validation Spec API", the jar is "geronimo-validation_1.0_spec-1.0-CR5.jar".
Look at this link :
http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-validation_1.0_spec/1.0-CR5/geronimo-validation_1.0_spec-1.0-CR5.jar.html
Here is maven part to add it :
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-validation_1.0_spec/1.0-CR5

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

depending on which version of the API you want to use. Note that the API is not enough, of course you also need an implementation (if you don't deploy your application in an Java EE application server). The implementation usually has a transitive dependency on the correct API jar.